Movie with a group of people trapped in a house/mansion with rollecoaster inside
I think its a movie from the 80s-90s and i remember watching it when i was 7-9 years old in the early 2000s. I think the movie is like combination of the classic comedy-thriller type. Its certainly an enjoyable show . 
Please help me though,i really want to watch it again so as to understand the show now that im an adult and i really miss it.
I remember theres a group of people being trap in a house/mansion and there is a roller coaster in the house. They are being kept there and they tried to escape. There is also a dinner scene with lots of food. The people in the movie are like monsters:fat,huge,ugly. There is also this last scene where i think a couple tried to escape through a car junkyard and theres this two ugly fat bald monsters chasing them. I think the pair manage to escape by a train thats beside the house.

A dinner scene with food? :)

This must be Nothing but trouble

A businessman finds he and his friends the prisoners of a sadistic judge and his equally odd family in the backwoods of a bizarre mansion. 

Everything you described is in the movie. 



Edit: Changed movie link, this video shows all scenes you describe...
